# Stream-Stream joins with mapGroupswithState in Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

What I am trying to achieve here is a SQL join between 2 streams. Since stream to stream joins is possible only in Spark 2.3., I am trying to see if I can leverage the `mapGroupswithState` API to achieve this.

I have 2 streams of data coming in Kafka - Orders and Customers.

The orders stream has the following fields : `OrderID`, `CustomerID`, `OrderDate`
The Customers stream has these fields: `CustomerID`, `CustomerName`, `ContactName`, `Country`

The relationship between the two streams above is the "CustomerID" field.

I need help in defining the mapping state function. I do not have any aggregates here, all I am trying to achieve is a simple join. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?